# ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout when inserting csv into oracle

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql

I'm trying to execute this code in PL/SQL:

```
create or replace directory ext_tab_dir as 'C:/mydir';
GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY ext_tab_dir TO PUBLIC;
DROP TABLE emp_load;
CREATE TABLE emp_load (v1 VARCHAR2(4000), 
                        v2 VARCHAR2(4000) 
                        )
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
     TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_dir
     ACCESS PARAMETERS (
     RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
     BADFILE ext_tab_dir:'bad.bad'
     LOGFILE ext_tab_dir:'log.log'
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','         
     )
     LOCATION ('testfile.csv')
   ); 
--   INSERT INTO tablename(v1,v2)
   SELECT * From emp_load
```

and then getting next errors:

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout    
ORA-29400: data cartridge error error opening file C:/mydir/log.log
```

I do get that it has to do something with permissions, but I'm the one who created that directory, so how do I grant priveleges to myself if it is set like this by default? Is there any way to perform that sort of operation from PL/SQL?

Comment: What's the content of the LOGFILE?

Comment: It's not in there as if it doesn't create itself, and If I do that manually it is empty.

Comment: Try writing the path with backslahes: `C:\mydir\log.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON emp_load TO NikitaBuriak;
```

Replace 'NikitaBuriak' with the ID you used when you created the table..

Comment: if I do so it says: ORA-01749 "you can't GRANT previleges to yourself"

Comment: You'll need to log into the database using an ID that has permissions to grant privileges against your table, then run the GRANT.

Comment: Trying to make such grant operation for external table should end with ORA-30657 error - "operation not supported on external organized table"...

Answer (score 2):

You should grant all the privileges to the directories and files in the location pointing to the file you are trying to access.

eg : if the file you are trying to excess is in `/home/dummy_folder/new_folder/file.txt` 
then you should grant all the administrative privileges to dummy_folder, new folder and file.txt as well

Comment: @VimalBhaskar, pardon me for my poor english. Will surely pay attention to the posted date . Thank you for your feedback!


and what i wanted to say by " GRANT ALL THE ADMINISTRATIVE PREVILAGES..." is the read/write/modify privileges. It worked for me.